# Passing seq-exprs to for using quoting

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to pass `seq-exprs` to `for` using quoting, but both of my attempts below result in `CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: for requires a vector for its binding`. I am clearly misunderstanding something about how quoting and evaluation (and related concepts) work.

```
(let [v ['b (range 2)]]
   (for v b))

(let [v '[b (range 2)]]
   (for v b))
```

What is the correct way to do it and how would you explain to begineer why none of the implementations above work? Thanks!

edit:
I know I can do

```
(let []
   (for [b (range 2)] b))
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to pass a vector of bindings (e.g. output of another function)

edit 2, motivation/background:
I am building a transpiler [[repo](https://github.com/talesa/bugs2foppl/)] and I'm trying to translate and unroll a for loop (including nested loops, [example](https://github.com/talesa/bugs2foppl/blob/master/examples/v1_dogs#L5)), so I thought that I could append ranges of variables to be iterated over to `seq-exprs` while traversing the AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) deeper through nested loops, and then evaluate the translated relationships (relationships can always be translated one by one) contained within each of the original for blocks given the 'bindings' generated by clojure `for`. Do you have advice if there is a 'better' way to do it?

Comment: at the end you wanna have something like: (for [i (0 1)])? What do you wanna achieve? You could use for like this: (for [i (range 2)] (println "i is: " i)), also for requires vector binding like this  ->[<your expression>]

Comment: This is a minimum example - I would like to be able to pass vector `seq-exprs` to `for` as a variable.

Comment: since `for` is a macro, which is expanded in compile time, meaning the bindings vector should be a literal vector, not a var, what you are trying to do is totally impossible (the compiler just doesn't know the runtime value of `v`). What you can do is to use another macro returning `for` macro (it still won't be able to operate on `v`'s runtime value) Or you can use `eval`, that is bad. Why do you even want to do this?

Comment: `for` produces a sequence. If you are always going to pass  the argument vector to `for`, why not just pass the sequence that `for` produces to whatever you wish to consume it?

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly the distinction between macros and functions. Functions take and return data at runtime. Macros, however, take and return *code* at *compile-time*.

Consider the following:

```
(defn foo [arg]
  (str arg))

(let [x (dec 10)]
  (foo x)) ;=> "9"
```

`foo` sees the integer 9 as the argument, because the current *runtime* value of `x` is 9. However, `foo` can't know that the value 9 was represented by the symbol `x`, because the symbol `x` is code.

```
(defmacro bar [arg]
  (str arg))

(let [x 9]
  (bar x)) ;=> "x"

(str 'x) => "x"
```

So if we change it to a macro, we get the compile time value of `x`, which is just the symbol `x`.

(We change it to a string, then it's returned as code, and the string `"x"` as code just evaluates to `"x"`.)

The important takeaway here is that in the same way `foo` can't know that it was passed something called `x`, it just knows that the runtime value is 9 , `bar` *only* knows it was passed something called `x`, it has no way of knowing what the runtime value of `x` is.

This is why macros are contagious.

So in your example, the *runtime* value of `v` is `'[b (range 2)]`, but the *compile-time* value that you pass to `for` is just the symbol `v` itself.

To solve your immediate problem, you could do something like this:

```
(let [v '[b (range 2)]]
  (eval `(for ~v ~'b)))
```

But that is just... horrible. What you probably want is to write a macro.

I'm not sure what this macro would look like, because I'd have to understand the actual problem that you want to solve, but here's an example of a macro that takes seq-exprs and passes them on to `for`.

```
;; Minimal example of a macro that takes seq-exprs as code
;; and returns code with a for that uses them.
(defmacro forv [seq-exprs body]
  `(vec (for ~seq-exprs ~body)))
```

Comment: I don't know about "probably". People asking this question usually actually want something like a cartesian product, which is better done as a function taking a list of lists and returning a list of tuples.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: @madstap I was trying to figure out how to use the macro you've provided to solve the problem, but I couldn't, could you give me an example? I've tried it in the following way 
`(let [v '[b (range 2)]
      body 'b]
  (macroexpand '(forv v body)))` 
and got
`(clojure.core/vec (clojure.core/for v body))`
. As you've explained the macro doesn't evaluate the runtime values of the arguments, so I don't see how I can solve it by writing a macro.

Comment: @tales The macro I wrote was meant as a minimal example of a macro that accepts seq-exprs and returns code with a `for` that uses them, sorry if that wasn't clear. I can't give you the solution as a macro because I don't know what you want. Your minimal example is [way too minimal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . 1/2

Comment: The value `'[b (range 2)] ` only exists at runtime, and by that time `for` has already taken its arguments and returned code based of those. To literally do what you say you want to do, there's the `eval` dance I described above as "horrible", but there's almost certainly a much simpler and easier solution if you take a step back and ask yourself "why" a couple times. 2/2

Comment: Yes, this is clearly the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), sorry about that and thanks for the link! I haven't heard about it before, I will now try to consciously avoid doing this. I've already provided a little more background at the bottom of my original post. If I can't solve the problem after asking myself why a few times I'll try to identify and describe X and ping you.

Comment: @tales Like amalloy says, maybe it'll help to take a look at `cartesian-product` in https://github.com/clojure/math.combinatorics

Answer (score -1):

`['b (range 2)] => ['b (0 1)]` with this example you have a symbol called `b` and also you are calling the function `(range 2)` which evals `(0 1)`

`'[b (range 2)] => [b (range)]` in this example you are quoting all expression so you end up having symbol `b` and `range symbol within a list data structure`.

About your for loop, you are getting that exception because you are not using it properly(missing vector binding).

This is how you should write a for loop:

```
(for [i (range 5)] ;;you need to define vector in here
     (do 
         (println "I: " i) 
         i));;let's return i here
```

Result:

```
I: 0
I: 1
I: 2
I: 3
I: 4
=> (0 1 2 3 4)
```